# How can i pass a parameter in Laravel from Request?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-excel

I fill a SQL Table from a Request with Laravel Excel.
After this I do an Eloquent Statement to fill the values markt and period manually.

```
public function importall(Request $request)
{
    $periode = $request->periode;
    $markt = $request->markt;
    Excel::import(new periodenImport(), $request->file);            // Datei Import

    /*
    PlanspielData::where('periode', ' ')                        
    ->update(['periode' => $periode]);                      // Daten der Periode zuordnen
   
    PlanspielData::where('markt', ' ')  
    ->update(['markt' => $markt]);                         // Daten einem Markt zuordnen
    */
    return redirect('/import')->with('success-upload', 'Sucess');
}
```

I want to pass more then the **file** from the Request to the newperiodenImport to delete the commented area with Planspieldata.

Comment: "I want to pass more then the file from the Request to the newperiodenImport to delete the commented area with Planspieldata." <<<=== Can you explain that one more time, please

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the request to anywhere, you can simply call `request()->input('X');`

Answer (score 0):

you can make a __construct in the class and pass data to it
example:

```
 class periodenImport implements ToCollection,WithHeadingRow,SkipsEmptyRows
    {
      private $periode;
      private $markt;
    
      public function __construct($periode, $markt)
      {
        $this->periode = $periode;
        $this->markt = $markt;
      }
    }
```

---

```
public function importall(Request $request)
{
  $periode = $request->periode;
  $markt = $request->markt;
   Excel::import(new periodenImport($periode,$markt), $request->file); 
}
```